# how to make multiple lines in label of container view

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, label

In a **ChallengeViewController** I have a Container View. In **ContentViewController** I have a label which is displayed in one line. Neither *Line Break*, nor *Number of Lines* didnt help.
Here is the link to my project: https://github.com/ardulat/auyrmahelp

Comment: Please point to a specific file. I don't see  ChallengeViewController or ContentViewController if those are file names.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala those are .swift files

Comment: In the storyboard, have you tried setting the number of lines of the label to 0? Setting it to 0 means the label's height will increase as per need. for e.g.- normal if only 1 line, twice the height if the text in label requires 2 lines of text.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala yes, i tried to do so, didnt help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by changing constraints: *Trailing* and *Leading* space, for instance make it greater or equal to 20 will be ok if you do so. And number of lines should be 0.

[Constraints for Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwj9Q.png)