# How to make long text label, which lives in UI View, to multiple lines in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to make a long text label, which lives inside of UI View, to multiple lines. I was searching for a solution for 2 hours, but I couldn't solve it, so I want to ask for some help. Here is the image of what I get now. [image]
This is the View Hierarchy debugger.[image]

In a table view cell, I put the repository name which I got from Github. In the third cell in the image, I want to make the repo name to two lines, since it's long. I saw [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857647/how-to-make-multiple-lines-in-label-of-container-view), which sounds similar to my current problem and implemented in my code, but it didn't work.

Here is my code. It's too long but the point is, I have declared `label.numberOfLines = 0` and `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`, and I tried to make my label convertible to multiple lines, but it didn't work. Could anyone please point me at what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    import UIKit

class RepositoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    let userImageView: UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.backgroundColor = .black

        return img
    }()
    
    let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        return view
    }()
    
    let userNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return label
    }()
    
    let repositoryNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .gray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return label
    }()
    
    let starNumLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .systemPink
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        return label
    }()
    

    
    //MARK: - Init

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubview(userImageView)
        containerView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(repositoryNameLabel)
        addSubview(containerView)
        addSubview(starNumLabel)
        
        configureUserNameLabel()
        configureRepositoryNameLabel()
 
        configureViewConstraints()
    }
    
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userImageView.frame.height / 2
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Helper functions
    
    func configureCellView(repository: Repository) {
        userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "001")
        userNameLabel.text = repository.userName
        repositoryNameLabel.text = repository.repositoryName
        starNumLabel.text = "⭐️\(String(describing: repository.starNum))"
    }
    
    
    func configureUserNameLabel() {
        userNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        userNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    func configureRepositoryNameLabel() {
        repositoryNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        repositoryNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
    
    func configureViewConstraints() {
        setUserImageConstraints()
        setContainerViewConstraints()
        setUserNameLabelConstraints()
        setRepositoryNameLabel()
        setStarNumLabel()
    }
    
    
    func setUserImageConstraints() {
        userImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        userImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        userImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
        userImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    }
    
    
    func setContainerViewConstraints() {
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: starNumLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    
    func setUserNameLabelConstraints() {
        userNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        userNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
//        userNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    
    func setRepositoryNameLabel() {
        repositoryNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        repositoryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userNameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        repositoryNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
//      repositoryNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

// this doesn't work...
//      repositoryNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true 
    }
    
    
    func setStarNumLabel() {
        starNumLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        starNumLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        starNumLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the trailing constraints of your label is not set properly.
You can use the View Hierarchy debugger in Xcode to have a clear view of the size your view actually has at runtime.

If the trailing anchor is not set, wrapping text isn't possible as it doesn't reach the "end" of the view.

Comment: As @Arthur already mentioned there are some trailing anchor constraints missing. Also I would suggest to set the vertical contentHuggingPriority to low (249) for multiline Labels e.g. repositoryNameLabel

Comment: @Arther Stefan Thank you so much for your response. So I updated my question and added a view hierarchy debugger. So when you guys say "missing trailing anchor", is that mean I should have my labels' trailing anchor exactly the same as UI view's trailing anchor? (sorry if I'm wrong)

Comment: Try to add a constraint (probably the one commented with doesn't work) ;-) but set it (at least for testing it solves the issue to equalToSuperview and use the trailing anchor of your container instead of the leading one.
repositoryNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

Comment: By the way if you want to play with auto layout constraints in swift, I highly recommend using SnapKit which is much more readable IMO